# Suddenly my software updater is giving error

Tags: xubuntu

My software updater is not opening(ubuntu 18.04LTS) and it says

> ```
> failed to run child process usr/bin/update-manager ("no such file or directory")
> ```

I am new to Ubuntu.

Comment: `sudo apt install --reinstall update-manager` If errors please edit your question and show them.